# Maintain coloring when subsetting data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to subset my data, but maintain the coloring generated when using all the data.

Here is all the data:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)) + 
    geom_point(shape = 21, aes(fill = Species), size=4, stroke=1)
```

which yields:

[image]

But if I subset on Species, such as virginica, the colors aren't preserved:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)) + 
    geom_point(data = subset(iris, Species=='virginica'), 
    shape = 21, aes(fill = Species), size=4, stroke=1)
```

[image]

I understand that this is probably the correct default behavior, but I'd like to maintain the color scheme for presentation purposes. How would I achieve this?

Bonus: Maintain the same axis dimensions as well

Comment: Use a `scale_fill_*` function to specify what color goes with what value, e.g. `scale_fill_manual(values = c('virginica' = 'dodgerblue'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use `scale_fill_manual` as suggested by @alistaire. Another way is to prevent dropping factor levels, but that will have the names of the levels in legends despite no data present for each level, not sure whether you want that. But that will give a full picture of the dataset, no matter which subset you select.

```
 ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)) + 
      geom_point(shape = 21, aes(fill = Species), size=4, stroke=1)

 ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)) + 
      geom_point(data = subset(iris, Species %in% c('virginica', 'setosa')), 
                 shape = 21, aes(fill = Species), size=4, stroke=1) +
      scale_fill_discrete(drop = FALSE)
```

[image]

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)) + 
      geom_point(data = subset(iris, Species=='virginica'), 
                 shape = 21, aes(fill = Species), size=4, stroke=1) +
      scale_fill_discrete(drop = FALSE)
```

[image]